# Converting Greek characters to Unicode

Tags: vb.net, unicode

Is there any easy way of converting a windows-1252 string into a Unicode one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All strings in .NET are Unicode in memory. 
If you have a *byte array* that was generated from a string encoded in 1252, you can recover the string using

```
Dim S as String = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(array)
```

It is now a unicode string in memory.  If you then want to encode that string into a UTF-8 byte array for transmission or storage, you would do the converse:

```
Dim A as byte() = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(S)
```

(I think that is the right VB syntax!)